# I get an error by reading an excel file using openpyxl (version 2.4.1)

Tags: openpyxl

The excel file is 200Mb with more than 1700 worksheets. Is there any limitation in openpyxl?

*TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'applyFillId'*

I tried with a smaller file and it is working so far

Answer (score 0):

File size is limited only by how much memory your computer has, though a file of that size should probably be opened in read-only mode. The error you're seeing has probably been fixed in a more recent version.